# Personal and work RSA keys on github and accessing respective computers

Tags: github, rsa

I have a personal RSA key attached to my personal github account. I have been told that if I also add my work RSA key to my personal account that it is possible to access one computer from the other using the keys.

Is this true? If so, what is the correct method of doing this (alias'?) or is this not recommended at all (separate accounts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct. The keys attached to your Github account are [public keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography). If you attach both personal and work public keys to your Github account, that account can be accessed by any computer which holds the corresponding private keys. However, your personal computer can't be accessed by your work computer, or vice versa, just because both public keys are on a single account at Github.

I've been using one Github account for work and non-work for years. Unless you don't want to be associated with your employer for some reason (or are doing some kind of open source work you don't want to associate with your employer) I don't see a problem with it. When you leave a job, just remove the appropriate public key from your account; it's up to your employer to remove your access to their repositories (should they wish to).